# Calculate $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}na(1-a)^{n-1}$, where $a \in (0,1)$.

Tags: sequences-and-series

Calculate $a\displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}n(1-a)^{n-1}$

where $a \in (0,1)$.

Comment: When you move a factor $a(1-a)$ out of the sum, do you recognize the series you then get?

Comment: I have changed the formatting of the title so as to make it take up less vertical space -- this is a policy to ensure that the scarce space on the main page is distributed evenly over the questions. See [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/9730) for more information. Please take this into consideration for future questions. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I post my above comment because I saw that you didn't accept any answer from your question. Please, consider my previous comment. Thanks.

Comment: [This question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/30732/how-can-i-evaluate-sum-n-0-infty-n1xn), again. It gives me an excuse to link [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/30732/how-can-i-evaluate-sum-n-0-infty-n1xn) once more.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetico-geometric_sequence#Series.2C_sum_to_n_terms and http://www.artofproblemsolving.com/Wiki/index.php/Arithmetico-geometric_series

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For fun (and this is probably not the solution you are expected to give) we give a **mean proof**. A certain coin has probability $a$ of landing heads, and probability $1-a$ of landing tails. The coin is tossed repeatedly. Let random variable $X$ be the number of tosses until we get the first head.

The probability that $X=1$ is $a$, the probability that $X=2$ is $(1-a)a$, the probability that $X=3$ is $(1-a)^2a$, and so on. It follows that the infinite sum we are asked to evaluate is $E(X)$, the mean of $X$.

Let us calculate this mean another way. Let the mean be $\mu$. Toss the coin.  With probability $a$, we get a head on the first toss, and $X=1$. With probability $1-a$ we get a tail on the first toss, and we have wasted a toss. The mean number of *additional* tosses needed in that case is $\mu$. Thus
$$\mu=(a)(1)+(1-a)(1+\mu).$$
Solve this linear equation for $\mu$. It turns out that $\mu=\dfrac{1}{a}$.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**: Consider the series:

$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} b^n = \frac{1}{1-b}$$

And take the derivative of both sides with respect to $b$. Now apply this to your series.

Answer (score 0):

Hints:

$$\forall\,x\in\Bbb C\;,\;|x|<1\;,\;\;f(x):=\frac1{1-x}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty x^n\implies$$

$$f'(x)=\frac1{(1-x)^2}=\sum_{n=1}^\infty nx^{n-1}\ldots\ldots$$